# Could not install package 'IEDriver 2.0.0'

Tags: c#, nuget, nuget-package, selenium-iedriver

I'm doing an UIAutomation Project in C# using Selenium. The automation is to be done in Internet Explorer. So I tried downloading IEDriver.exe from NuGet Package Manager but faced following error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error 
>         Could not install package 'IEDriver 2.0.0'. You are trying to
>   install this package into a project that targets
>   '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1', but the package does not contain any
>   assembly references or content files that are compatible with that
>   framework. For more information, contact the package author.          0

I've few confusions over this warning.

- **the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework**

What are those assembly references and content files which are compatible for my targer gramework version v4.6.1?

Answer (score 0):

If you look inside the IEDriver 2.0 NuGet package it just contains a single file: IEDriverServer.exe.

You cannot install this NuGet package into a project. It does not have any lib directories so NuGet will not be able to add it to your project.